# Angularjs Filter ng-options for unique values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wanting to filter unique values from ng-options. I get nothing but duplicated entries and if I a model I get a whole bunch of blank rows. I've created a plunk. An assistance is appreciated.

thanks in advance

http://plnkr.co/edit/UCI6mVHjEiyZTYUpQ18Y?p=preview

```
<select ng-options="c.metaInfo.subType for c in myArray">
```

Comment: But $scope.myArray is not an array...

Comment: $scope.myArray =  "Results":{
    "type":"application/doc", ... it's not an object either

Comment: check your `myArray` value - it's invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tNhY148xfgMH4Jh4I2X?p=preview)

Your code has several problems: first of all `myArray` isn't neither an object or an array, it's a wrong syntax, check mine instead.

Then to use `ng-options` you need to set an `ng-model` too.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("Test", function($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [{
        "type": "application/doc",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "metaInfo": {
            "subType": "doc",
            "filesize": "60kb"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "application/pdf",

        "metaInfo": {
            "subType": "pdf",
            "filesize": "60kb"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "application/xls",

        "metaInfo": {
            "subType": "xls",
            "filesize": "60kb"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "application/pdf",

        "metaInfo": {
            "subType": "pdf",
            "filesize": "60kb"
        }
    }];
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="Test">
     <select ng-options="c.metaInfo.subType for c in myArray | unique:'metaInfo.subType'" ng-model="selected">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected: {{selected || "None"}}</p>
  </body>
```

To remove duplicates you need an Angular module like [this one](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) to use the filter `unique`.

I updated the Plunker with all you need.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys, it makes sense. How do I remove the duplicate entries?

Comment: How do I remove the duplicate entries from the dropdown?

Comment: I updated the answer to remove also duplicates, please consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your html code like this

```
<select  ng-model="subType" ng-options="c.metaInfo.subType for c in myArray">
        <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

and need to follow array syntax. Use below code:

```
$scope.myArray = [
    {
      "type": "application/doc",
      "url": "www.google.com",
      "metaInfo": {
        "subType": "doc",
        "filesize": "60kb"
      },

    },
    {
      "type": "application/pdf",
      "metaInfo": {
        "subType": "pdf",
        "filesize": "60kb"
      },

    },
    {
      "type": "application/xls",
      "metaInfo": {
        "subType": "xls",
        "filesize": "60kb"
      },

    },
    {
      "type": "application/pdf",
      "metaInfo": {
        "subType": "pdf",
        "filesize": "60kb"
      },

    }
  ];
```